# Factor vs. ordered factor?

Tags: r, r-factor

Here is the problem that I'm trying to solve. I'm using `burn` dataset from `KMsurv` library and I'm trying to fit a simple survival model with two simple covariates. One of these predictors is an ordered factor. Perhaps my question is a naive question, When I look at the result, I see the words `L` and `Q` in front of my estimated coefficients. Do `L` and `Q` refer to linear and quadratic? I expected to see the same number of estimated coefficients but with different estimates when I adjusted an ordered factor compared to adjusting the same factor which is not ordered. Could you guide me on what the result of my fit means (those coeff with `Q` and `L`) and how they should be interpreted? I appreciate if you could also refer me to a reference to learn more about adjusting ordered factors.
Here is my code:

```
library(KMsurv)
data(burn)
names(burn) <- c("Obs", "TRT", "Female", "White", "SurfBurned", "HeadBurned",
"buttBurned", "TrunkBurned", "UpperLegBurned", "LowerLegBurned", "resp", 
"BurnType", "ExcisionTime", "ExcisionDelta", "prophylacticTime",
"ProphylacticDelta", "straphylInfTime", "straphylInfDelta")

burn$SurfBurned_cat <- factor(cut(burn$SurfBurned, c(0, 10, 25, 100), 
labels = c("low", "medium", "high")),  

levels = c("low", "medium", "high"), ordered = TRUE)
Q4PcCoxModel <- coxph(Surv(straphylInfTime, straphylInfDelta) ~
                       TRT*SurfBurned_cat, 
                      data = burn)
summary(Q4PcCoxModel)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `burn$SurfBurned`. The column does not appear to exist, actually, none of the columns you refer to exist in `burn`

Comment: for ordered factors R generates orthogonal polynomial contrasts, using `contr.poly`.  L and Q do indeed refer to "linear" and "quadratic" ...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I renamed the columns and I forgot to put that in here. Just edited!

Comment: I appreciate your answer, @BenBolker.

Comment: I found this webpage (section 4 specifically) quite useful in working out what R was doing with my ordered factors. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use treatment contrasts for ordered factors, you can set this globally using this command `options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.treatment"))`. However, your expectation is incorrect:

> I expected to see the same number of estimated coefficients but with different estimates when I adjusted an ordered factor compared to adjusting the same factor which is not ordered.

Adjusting for an ordered factor using treatment contrasts will give you the same estimates as adjusting for a for an unordered factor using treatment contrasts.